# Creating a facility/equipment through c# code with work hours setting var-by-day

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I was trying to create a facility/equipment and setting its work hours through c# code, i am successfully able to create the facility and set its work hours.
I am able to set the work hours at Freq = Daily/Weekly.
The problem i am facing right now is i am not able to set different timings for different days (Freq = weekly), what is happening is the timings are getting set for all the days in the week and if i change one of the timings all the timings of other days gets changed.

Ex: I set timings like this

```
calendarRule1.Attributes["duration"] = 540;
calendarRule1.Attributes["offset"] = 480;
calendarRule1.Attributes["timezonecode"] = 190;
```

for the calendar rule as shown below:

```
calendarRule.Attributes["duration"] = 1440; 
calendarRule.Attributes["pattern"] = "FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR";
calendarRule.Attributes["timezonecode"] = 190;
```

The above code adds work hours from Monday to Friday with work hours (8 AM to 5 PM ) 
Can someone assist me with code as to how to set different work hours on different days i.e. Vary-by-day.

Thanks in advance
(code snippet is just an example shown - i have all the supporting code added)

Answer (score 0):

Change the BYDAY value to only specify the day(s) you want to set:

For example, to just set for Tuesday and Wednesday:

'es["pattern"] = "FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TU,WE"'

Comment: I am concerned about setting different timings on different days.........its not about only different days.